# Making flag depend on counter c#

Tags: c#

I want to make a flag that depend on cntkotak on my program. Here I have cntkotak that will count until 3. During cntkotak counting, my flag variable will increase depend on value of cntkotak. For example My cntkotak value is 3 and my flag will be flag3 = true. If my cntkotak value is 2, my flag will be flag2 = true. It's kinda bool flag + cntkotak = true, but it doesn't work. That's my idea but I don't know how to implement it. Please help me

```
foreach (var filePath in templateImage)
{
    counterbanyaktemplate++;
    for (cntkotak = 0; cntkotak < banyakkotak; cntkotak++)
    {
        Image<Bgr, byte> templates = new Image<Bgr, byte>(filePath);
        imageToShow.ROI = new Rectangle(x1 + ((tempwidth / banyakkotak) * cntkotak), y1, tempwidth / banyakkotak, tempheight);                        
        using (Image<Gray, float> result = imageToShow.MatchTemplate(templates, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TM_TYPE.CV_TM_CCOEFF_NORMED))
        {
            double[] maxValues, minValues;
            Point[] maxLoc, minLoc;
            result.MinMax(out minValues, out maxValues, out minLoc, out maxLoc);


            if (counterbanyaktemplate == ((cntkotak + 1) + (banyakkotak * pengali)))
                {
                    if (maxValues[0] > 0.8)
                    {
                      //here i want to make a flag that depend on cntkotak.
                   if(flag == true)
                  {

                            Rectangle match = new Rectangle(x1 + ((tempwidth / banyakkotak) * cntkotak), y1, tempwidth / banyakkotak, tempheight);

                            newImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Green), 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Rectangle match = new Rectangle(x1 + ((tempwidth / banyakkotak) * cntkotak), y1, tempwidth / banyakkotak, tempheight);
                            newImage.Draw(match, new Bgr(Color.Red), 1);
                        }

                        if (cntkotak == banyakkotak - 1)
                        {
                            cntkotak = -1;
                            pengali++;
                        }
                        if (pengali == banyakkotak - 1)
                        {
                            pengali = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }    
        }
```

Comment: Why use a flag at all? Why not just test `if (cntkotak == 1) { /*...*/ }` etc.?

Comment: So here I am going to make a template matching program using Emgu CV C#. I have 3 boxes and cntkotak is represent my each boxes. My program will scan number of templates in my directory using counterbanyaktemplate and counterbanyaktemplate will increase depend on cntkotak. So, if there is template has maxValues > 0.9, my flag will be true. That's why I want to make a flag that the variable is programatically same like cntkotak value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to set multiple flag values,then I think you can have a bool array for flags, then set appropriate value based on the cntkotak value.i.e use  cntkotak  value as index for the array and set it true or false.

Comment: Thanks so mu Venkatesh :)